# Is Wish.com trustworthy and worth it?

Tags: scams

I don't know if this question belongs here. Heck, I don't know where else it would go. Please inform me where it would further benefit others, or if it's simply off-topic.

I am interested in making slime for my friend. It is garbage, but they like it so might as well do something for them. However, I don't want to waste too much money. Going to the dollar store is an option, but they don't have everything needed to create slime, especially the beads. I saw a couple of them on wish.com at a decent price. But I'm afraid that it's a scam, because I've noted that a lot of items on that site have gigantic discounts just randomly.

Has anyone tried wish.com yet or know that it's trustworthy and worth the money?

Comment: Off-topic here, but this reddit thread seems to address it: https://www.reddit.com/r/IsItBullshit/comments/7xjawn/isitbullshit_is_wish_a_legit_online_store_and_is/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wish is a super-pipeline for cheap Cheese products of very low quality, much like AliExpress, and most items on eBay or Amazon Marketplace.

These products ignore all the consumer product safety standards (i.e. Do not comply with them, i.e. Are likely to be unsafe). They do that by  using a loophole (cheat) in our trade agreements.

if that suits your needs, go for it.

Comment: So everything on sold is safe, just super cheap? Are the sellers trust-worthy?

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry Wish.com is trust-worthy (most of the time) website. If the items aren't received they are giving you a refound pretty quickly. Don't expect high quality products tho. Also, don't buy items like GPU on Wish, those are generally fake items. Like Harper said, Wish items are mostly alibaba and aliexpress items. I personnaly don't order anything here, but I know a lot of people who used to order on Wish.com and they didn't have any problems, just don't expect high quality items.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry they are not safe.   WhenI say "bypass the safety standards" I don't mean they follow them, I mean they ignore safety.

Comment: @Harper Ah okay. I won't be buying any technology.

Comment: Don't buy anything that might potentially have lead or poison in it, either.

Comment: @Harper Does Wish even sell such items?

Comment: They sell loads of things that are *not supposed to* have poison or lead in them, but might if made wrong.  Point is, nobody's checking or testing these products.