# Is Tiller a trustworthy for tracking personal finance & budgeting?

Tags: budget, security, software

I want to track my personal transactions with spreadsheets and do budgeting there. I came across https://www.tillerhq.com, which seems to solve that perfectly. I want to be smart about who I expose my financial information to though. Is there any way to verify if a company is trustworthy/has built reasonably secure software? The way tiller works is by talking to your bank with your username/password through [yodlee.com](https://www.yodlee.com/) and then dumping your transactions into a google spreadsheet once a day at 1am.

Other bits related to trusthworthiness/security:

- How Tiller works is outlined here: https://www.tillerhq.com/security
- Tiller seems to have an endorsement from microsoft: https://www.tillerhq.com/tiller-microsoft-partnership/
- I plan to use google sheets, but presumably google isnt doing anything interesting with personal transactions in a spreadsheet, that seems too specialized for google to care about stalking my amazon purchases

Comment: I've voted to close this because product recommendations aren't allowed here. However, if you want to dive into the security in full, you'll need to look at the policies for Tiller, Yodlee, and Google individually.

Comment: @StanH is there another place you can suggest where I can ask questions about how trustworthy a product is? I based this question off of ones like this https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/103338/is-wish-com-trustworthy-and-worth-it

Comment: What is your point in referencing that other question? It was closed within 30 minutes for being off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to reframe the question into one that will do you, and everyone else, more good in the future -- because any concrete answer given this week may be invalid next year.

Same advice as anything else asking you to give them your bank credentials: Research them. Check how long their domain name has existed. Check that where it's registered from, the phone number they give, and their stated address (if you can find it) all line up. If you can figure out which state they are (claiming to be) incorporated in, ask that state's Secretary's office or equivalent for their financial statements. (This can sometimes be accessed via the state's website.) Websearch, and possibly check their state's Better Business Bureau (they may not be members) to see if there is a history of complaints against them. Since they are going through yodlee.com, check that company too.

Basically, treat anything of this sort as unsafe until you have plenty of evidence that it isn't a scam and/or a security  breach waiting to happen. The latter, admittedly, is harder to predict.

This is why I strongly prefer financial tools that keep the data on my own machine rather than in the cloud, or at least that are actively backed (rather than hinting at possible backing) by major, long-established firms who have a history showing that they can protect data. And why I do *not* give anyone but my own banks authority to actually issue transactions; if access is read-only there's a lot less damage that can be done.

Comment: Whois reports that the domain tillerhq.com is based in Toronto and was created in 2018. Websearch doesn't find any obvious indication that they're especially suspicious. I'd dig further, but I see no immediate reason to panic... assuming that you are dealing with who you think you're dealing with.

Comment: Note that your own bank is or brokers or employer benefits contractor may offer something equivalent, though probably not in spreadsheet form per se.